# iOS: Proper way to display required UITextField in UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, uitextfield

I have tried google and looked at the iOS Human Interface Guidelines but cannot seem to find anything on the best practices for displaying that a UITextField inside of a custom Grouped UITableViewCell is required.

Is there any recommendations or has anyone seen how other applications do it? I am basically creating a form dynamically and need to let the user know some way that certain fields MUST be filled out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally, an asterisk is a good idea. If you use placeholder text, then when the user fills in the box, they can't see it anymore --- so a filled-in form wouldn't tell you which fields were mandatory or not.

I would put a small `UILabel` next to the `UITextField`, and have that `UILabel` contain an asterisk, probably in red.

Or, if most of the fields are required, then you can use placeholder text in the optional fields, that says *(optional)*

Also, you can create a method that checks if all the required fields are completed. If they aren't, then disable the "Continue" button. If they are, then enable the "Continue" button. Call this method via a `UITextFieldDelegate` method.

Comment: The problem with using "*" is that it takes space. I do not recall any app that uses the web standards for alarming the user about required fields.

Comment: This isn't about web standards --- it's about what users expect on forms. It's a well-known indicator that a field is mandatory if there is an asterisk next to the field.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the UITextField placeholder property to display the text "Name is required". This will indicate to the user that the field is required and must be filled.

Comment: Placeholders should not be used to tell people what is required. Like said below if text is in the field then how will people know they are required?